# Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.CompositionEngine and Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Presentation.Core cannot add to Silverlight Project

Tags: silverlight, assemblies, scom

I am authoring a management pack with custom views using Silverlight / WPF (shared code) and MP authoring console and MP authoring tool in Visual Studio.
I am following this tutorial on custom views. 
[Widget for SCOM operation and web console - custom](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12324.creating-a-widget-for-operations-manager-dashboard-walkthrough-1-custom-ui-control.aspx?Sort=MostRecent&PageIndex=1#Add_a_Property_to_AlertData_class_to_Receive_SCOM_Data)

In Section 4.1: It mentions: Add a reference to **Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.CompositionEngine** and **Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Presentation.Core** assemblies.  These can typically be found in the Console folder of the Operations Manager installation. Attention: the assemblies from the RTM/CU1 installation will not work! You need to download the sample project files   and use the included assemblies.

I cannot add references to the Silverlight project. I get an error message:

[image: assemblies not built against Silverlight runtime]

Is there any way to get around this?

I understand that the .net runtime is different than that of Silverlight. Yet, this tutorial shows a working example, so it there a missing step or a different binary. What am I missing?

Comment: I am using SL5. Will test that and get back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In Section 4.1: It mentions: Add a reference to Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.CompositionEngine and Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Presentation.Core assemblies. These can typically be found in the Console folder of the Operations Manager installation. Attention: the assemblies from the RTM/CU1 installation will not work! **You need to download the sample project files and use the included assemblies.***

The important bit is the bit in bold, you need to download the sample project and copy the references from there. Were you doing this?

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Creating-a-Widget-for-104711ac

If you download this zip and go to the following sub directory

\Creating a Widget for Operations Manager Dashboard - Walkthrough %231.zip\Creating a Widget for Operations Manager Dashboard - Walkthrough #1\Section_4\AlertSummarySilverlight\Bin\Debug

You'll see the two assemblies in this folder. Copying them out of the zip into another folder and add a reference to them. This works for me in Silverlight 5.

Comment: Just realized that when I downloaded the project weeks ago, I forgot to make name smaller so all dlls with longer path didn't install! I made a stupid mistake and skip! now I can see these dlls and reference them after I unblock them.

Comment: Thanks. Before I didn't see the dlls in Silverlight but in the WPF file only. It was the long path name issue!

Comment: I will. Just waiting since it doesn't allow me to award immediately. I have 6 hours from now. Don't worry :D